# rich editor for notes in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, crm

all! 
I'm trying to add rich text editor for Notes on Entities in crm 2011. I found a useful [tutorial how to add WYSIWYG Editor to TextArea](http://www.crmsoftwareblog.com/2011/06/adding-wysiwyg-editor-to-textarea-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm-part-2-crm-2011/), but how can I apply this for Notes? or there are another ways to solve my problem?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below text editor and it is good one.

http://chamarairesh.blogspot.com/2013/07/rich-text-box-with-crm-2011-rollup-12.html

I have not try this with note section.

Below link will give you some idea.

http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e4f034f6-c077-4bfd-aca8-f7673e88379b/adding-a-wysiwyg-editor-on-notes?forum=crmdevelopment

Answer (score 0):

You will have to implement some kind of HTML editor on the form with a backing field. Thereafter, in a "post create" or a "post update" plugin for the entity in question, add the text saved in the backing field to the Annotations entity with the ObjectId set to the EntityReference of the entity in question. In order to implement a HTML editor with a backing field, you can use one of the following options available to you:

- [crmhtmleditor](https://crmhtmleditor.codeplex.com/)
- [xrmtinymce](https://xrmtinymce.codeplex.com/)

[Here's](http://www.c2software.com/c2-blog/add-note-to-crm-entity.aspx) a code snippet in VB to add a note programmatically. You can always translate that to C#.